# Question on permission needed to add users (at least partner users) to public group

Tags: user-management, public-group

I have created a delegated administration that allows a full salesforce internal user to create public groups.  They can add roles, and other public groups to existing public groups, and ones they create, but they cannot add partner users.  If I give them the "Manage Users" permission, they will have the access they need, but they can also edit profiles, which I do not want them to be able to do.  Is there any other way to give them access to add partner users to public groups without the "Manage Users" permission? They already have the Manage External Users permission, but this doesn't give them that access, which is strange to me.